# Android TextView doesn't update

Tags: android, textview

I am developing an Android app. Please see the Java code below. Can you please explain why textView doesn't update at specific lines in code but updates at others. I have them commented in the code.

I have updated the code see below. 
The idea is to get a facebook profile from a server. When profiling_status equals 2 means that the profile is not ready, so I'll just ping the server until I get profiling_status != 2.. 
I tried the progress dialog thingy but gave up cause I put my activity in a thread, but then I couldn't get some information because I should have run it in nonUIThread.. Tried that but I failed and I lost patience.. so decided that while I ping the server I should just print "Loading profile. Please wait." No mess, no fuss! Only as said, textView doesn't update. Interestingly enough.. System.out.println("Here"); gets executed. I am running it only on AVD at the moment cause the server is not on the wireless network so I can't use a mobile phone to test it.

```
public class SelectionFragment extends Fragment {

    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
    private TextView userNameView;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;
    private TextView textView;
    private String username = null;
    Context context;
    JSONObject json = null;
    JSONObject json_facebook = null;
    int time = 0;
    int time_interval = 3000;
    int profiling_status = 2;
    String logincode;
    String usermessage = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
            uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, final Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private void deleteProfile() throws JSONException {
        IDThiefHTTPRequest.deleteProfile();
        textView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText("Press Get profile info button to process your risk of identity theft");

        //Facebook logout
        Session session2 = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session2 != null) {
            session2.close();
        }
        else {
            session2 = new Session(context);
            Session.setActiveSession(session2);
            session2.close();
        }
    }

    private String readRiskScoreArray(JSONArray json_riskscore) throws NumberFormatException, JSONException{

        //get the risk score with only two digits 
        double risk_score = Double.valueOf(json_riskscore.get(0).toString());
        String risk_score2digits = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(risk_score);

        String usermessage = "Your risk score is: ";
        usermessage = usermessage + risk_score2digits;
        usermessage = usermessage + " which is ranked as: ";
        usermessage = usermessage + json_riskscore.get(2).toString();

        JSONArray json_reasons = json_riskscore.getJSONArray(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < json_reasons.length(); i++){
            JSONArray json_reason = json_reasons.getJSONArray(i);
            JSONArray json_reasondetails = json_reason.getJSONArray(1);
            usermessage = usermessage + "\n\nReason: ";
            usermessage = usermessage + json_reasondetails.get(0);
            usermessage = usermessage + "\n\nIDThief suggests you to: ";
            usermessage = usermessage + json_reasondetails.get(1);
            usermessage = usermessage + "\n\nFix it through this link:\n";
            usermessage = usermessage + json_reasondetails.get(2);
        }

        return usermessage;
    }


    private void displayProfileInfo() throws JSONException {

      Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
      if (session.isOpened()) {
            System.out.println(session.getAccessToken());
      }
      if (username != null) {
          System.out.println("Login stage: Getting profile info for user:" + username);
          logincode = username + "!" + session.getAccessToken();

          json = IDThiefHTTPRequest.makeLoginHTTPRequest(logincode);
          System.out.println(json.toString(4));
          json_facebook = json.getJSONObject("facebook");
          //profiling_status
          profiling_status = Integer.valueOf(json_facebook.get("profiling_status").toString());

          if (profiling_status == 2) {

              try {
                  while (profiling_status == 2 && time < 100000) {

                     textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                     textView.setGravity(Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
                     textView.setText("Loading profile. Please wait.");
                     System.out.println("Here");


                     try {
                            Thread.sleep(time_interval);
                            time += time_interval;
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                      }

                      json = IDThiefHTTPRequest.makeLoginHTTPRequest(logincode);
                      json_facebook = json.getJSONObject("facebook");
                      //profiling_status
                      profiling_status = Integer.valueOf(json_facebook.get("profiling_status").toString());

                 }

                 if (time >= 100000) {
                     System.out.println("Time is out");
                     textView.setText("Server is not responding. Please try again later.");
                 }


               }
               catch (Exception e)
              {
                   e.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
          JSONArray json_riskscore = json_facebook.getJSONArray("risk_score");
          System.out.println(json_riskscore.toString(4));

          usermessage = readRiskScoreArray(json_riskscore);
          textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
          textView.setGravity(Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
          textView.setText(usermessage);


      }
      else System.out.println("username is null");

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selection, 
                container, false);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        Button deletebutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton2);

        deletebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
              public void onClick(View v)
              {
                try {
                    deleteProfile();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
        });

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profiletext);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
            try {
                displayProfileInfo();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
          }
        });

        // Find the user's profile picture custom view
        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) view.findViewById(R.id.selection_profile_pic);
        profilePictureView.setCropped(true);

        // Find the user's name view
        userNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selection_user_name);

        // Check for an open session
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // Get the user's data
            makeMeRequest(session);
        }

        return view;
    }

    private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
        // Make an API call to get user data and define a 
        // new callback to handle the response.
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, 
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // If the response is successful
                if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        // Set the id for the ProfilePictureView
                        // view that in turn displays the profile picture.
                        profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                        // Set the Textview's text to the user's name.
                        userNameView.setText(user.getName());
                        username = user.getUsername();
                        //System.out.println("Log in=====================================");
                    }
                }
                if (response.getError() != null) {
                    // Handle errors, will do so later.
                }
            }
        });
        request.executeAsync();
    } 

    private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // Get the user's data.
            makeMeRequest(session);
        }
        else if (session != null && session.isClosed()) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setText("Press Get profile info button to process your risk of identity theft");

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide full code if you can

Comment: what you want see?  `Loading profile. Please wait.` or `Done`?

Comment: we want to see what is the values of `profiling_status` and `time` through code.

Comment: what is `getProfilingStatus();` and how you get the `time`?

Comment: what is the datatype of profiling_status  variable

Comment: The code gets executed cause I have a system.out where I setText.. I'll try to post the whole code but it's pretty big. I cleaned it up for this question.

Comment: P.S. I also get alot of Skipped xx frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread... It's my second Android app, so not very experienced

Answer (score 0):

I thing your username is a string . Normally it will be so use `!username.equals()` dont use `!=` in string comparison. that code may not get executed

Answer (score 0):

```
if (username != null  || !username.equals("")) { 
//to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below to compare the string do not use `==` use `equalsIgnoreCase()` or `equals()` method.

```
 if (profiling_status.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
            //would not update here either
            try {
                while (profiling_status.equalsIgnoreCase("2") && time < 100000) {
                    textView.setText("Loading profile. Please wait.");
                     try {
                           Thread.sleep(time_interval);
                           time += time_interval;
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                     }
```

Comment: Try out as `String.valueOf(profiling_status).equalsIgnoreCase("2")` @user1406975